# How to mount different NFS volumes depending on the connected network?

Tags: 11.10, mount, fstab, nfs

**Scenario:**
I use the same notebook at work and at home:

- At work I have 13 NFS mappings split over two different IPs.
- At home I have one mapping on a third IP.

**Problem:**
When I get home and turn on the notebook, it takes a long time to boot due to the missing IPs present on my fstab.

**Solution:**
Maybe there is a way to add conditional blocks on fstab or perhaps use different fstab files depending on the network I am connected to.

**Is that possible or is there an alternate solution?**

Comment: Update your question if you need help with autofs. I need more specific information to write a config for you, but I would be happy to review your config if you pastebin it.

Comment: This really shouldn't be closed.  This has gotten much less uncommon since 2011.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best solution is autofs.

The syntax of autofs takes a few minutes to comprehend, but once you understand the syntax it is very very easy and very much automated.

The advantage is that your shares are mounted, automatically, seamlessly, but only as needed. So no more slow boots, yet the shares are easily available.

> autofs is a program for automatically mounting directories on an as-needed basis. Auto-mounts are mounted only as they are accessed, and are unmounted after a period of inactivity. Because of this, automounting NFS/Samba shares conserves bandwidth and offers better overall performance compared to static mounts via fstab.

Install autofs

```
sudo apt-get install autofs
```

You then remove the mounts from /etc/fstab and add them to `/etc/auto.master`

The syntax is

> mount-point [map-type[,format]:] map [options]

For example:

```
mount-point   -fstype=nfs4   server:/share
```

You can mount all the shares on a particular server, for example

```
/media/work-server   /etc/auto.work-server
```

will mount all the shares on your work server, in the directory `/media/work-server` as configured in `/etc/auto.work-server`

If you have a problem, paste bin your configuration file(s) and we can review them.

See : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs